# Synchronization problem

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
  public class PingPong implements Runnable {
      synchronized void hit(long n) {
          for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
              System.out.print(n + "-" + i + " ");
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          new Thread(new PingPong()).start();
          new Thread(new PingPong()).start();
      }
      public void run() {
          hit(Thread.currentThread().getId());
      }
  }
```

The above code gives me output 8-1 9-1 8-2 9-2
But as the function is synchronized it should give output **8-1 8-2 9-1 9-2 or 9-1 9-2 8-1 8-2**
Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'synchronized' on a method synchronizes all accesses of that method *on a particular object*.

So if you have 1 `PingPong` object no 2 threads will simultaneously enter its `hit` method, but with 2 objects one thread can enter the `hit` method of one of the objects while another thread runs the `hit` object of the other.

This makes sense because you usually use `synchronized` to ensure undisturbed access to stuff local to the current object. If your object represents some external entity to which threads sometimes need undisturbed access, make your object a singleton.

Comment: @Android Or you could fix it by making `hit` a static method.  In that case `synchronize` synchronizes on `PingPong.class` instead of on the 2 different instances.

Comment: @tota Well you could, but that sounds like extremely bad design. You need some object to represent the current game state anyhow so synchronizing on that seems much nicer

Answer (score 4):

To get the behaviour you want, try making the following change:

```
 public class PingPong implements Runnable {
      synchronized void hit(long n) {
          for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
              System.out.print(n + "-" + i + " ");
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          PingPong p = new PingPong();
          new Thread(p).start();
          new Thread(p).start();
      }
      public void run() {
          hit(Thread.currentThread().getId());
      }
  }
```

With only a single instance of `PingPong`, the `synchronized` modifier on `hit()` will prevent one thread from interrupting the other, and your output will be either `X-1 X-2 Y-1 Y-2` or visa-versa.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

> First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods
>   on the same object to interleave.

So since you have two PingPong objects the synchronized keyword does not work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Nope .. synchronized simply mean that a specific method will not be executed by two threads at the same time, but if you have two threads working they can call that method in any order anyway. Simply, they will not access at the same time.

Moreover, it synchronizes on the object instances. Being two instances, there is no synchronization at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have no lock or unlock flags. so they will both run at the same time.

> T1->run()->hit(); forloop
>   T2->run()->hit(); forloop

Comment: @Mark -- something to block the 2nd thread from running until the 1st thread is finished

Comment: @Neal That's what the OP wants to happen with `synchronized`. And it *would* work if he had only one instance of `PingPong`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
public class PingPong2 implements Runnable {

private static Object obj = new Object();
    void hit(long n) {
     synchronized(obj)
     {
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        System.out.print(n + "-" + i + " ");
     }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new PingPong2()).start();
    new Thread(new PingPong2()).start();
}
public void run() {
    hit(Thread.currentThread().getId());
  }   }
```